# What is the difference between samba.conf and smb.conf

Tags: samba, smb

I have both a `samba.conf` and `smb.conf` file in the `/etc/samba` directory. What is the difference between them?

Comment: For my Ubuntu 16.04 server computers, I do not have a file called `/etc/samba/samba.conf`. I only have `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, which is the main samba configuration file.

Comment: My systems look the same as @DougSmythies do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `smb.conf` file is the configuration file for setting up and managing the samba server.  It's where you setup your shares and the behavior of the server.

The `samba.conf` file is part of the operation of the server.  It is part of the server's system's management.  This is a part of the behavior at boot which includes functions such as management and cleanup of work files.